# HTML embedded in Boolean parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a boolean method parameter to show a glyph based on if its True or False.
Like this:

```
<td><%= a.correct ? "glyphicon glyphicon-ok" : "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %></td>
```

It needs the HTML embedded, I tried:

```
{<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></li>'} : {'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></li>}
```

and

```
<td><%= a.correct ? "<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></li>" : "<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></li>" %></td>
```

And with parenthesis, no parenthesis, etc. I cannot find the documentation on this. :( So I don't know how to do the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert ruby code inside the string, something like:

```
<td><span class="<%= a.correct ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove' %>"></td>
```

Comment: Yeah this works, just puts the glyphs in '' like this: <td><span class="<%= a.correct ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove' %>"></td> Can you update so I can approve answer